# How to configure multiple Gradle test tasks without duplicate execution?

Tags: java, gradle, testing, groovy

I have a Spring Boot project configured with Gradle. There are several JUnit5 tests, some of which are 'rest-docs' tests and the others are 'non-rest-docs' tests. Here I made this distinction to group those tests that output Spring REST docs snippets. Since Spring REST docs requires document snippets to be generated before the final REST document generation, I found it reasonable that the `asciidoctor` Gradle task depends on a task that runs all 'rest-docs' tests.

So, I have three test-type tasks: `restDocsTest`, `nonRestDocsTest`, and `test`. I annotated all 'rest-docs' tests with `@Tag("rest-docs")` so that it can be filtered by JUnit runner as:

```
tasks.register('restDocsTest', Test) {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags "rest-docs"
    }
}
```

I configured `nonRestDocsTest` in the same way except for using `excludeTags` instead of `includeTags`.

For `test` task, I just made it depend on the other two tasks:

```
tasks.named('test') {
    dependsOn restDocsTest, nonRestDocsTest
}
```

Everything looked fine until I ran `test` task with a filter, something like `--tests com.example.foo.*`. This happens when I want to run different types of tests in a package together with one shot. When I pass `--tests` argument to the `test` task, it seems that it does not affect the execution of `restDocsTest` and `nonRestDocsTest` and just all tests are executed by those two tasks regardless of the filter.

Then I tried to make `test` task run tests by itself like:

```
tasks.named('test') {
    outputs.dir snippetsDir
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

It seemes that it solves the problem, but it didn't. When I run a task that depends on both `test` and `asciidoctor` tasks, both `test` and `restDocsTest` tasks are executed. And I found that JUnit platform is not smart enough to avoid duplicate test execution. That is, the same tasks are executed twice by `test` and `restDocsTest` tasks.

**Here is my question**: is there a way that I can pass on `--tests` filter to other tests that `test` task depends on when `test` task is executed? If it's not possible, then can I make `test` task recognize already executed tests by other test tasks and avoid re-running them?